# Getting wrong item on using getItem(position) in getView() method of a Custom ListView Adapter with a CheckBox for each list items and a search bar

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I have a ListView with a photo , Name and a CheckBox in each row of the ListView. The activity containing the List also contains a search bar which I have implemented using EditText and TextChangedListener, the list also enabled for multiple choice mode. Normally when there is nothing in the search bar, the CheckBox returns the right position of the item in the list.But as soon as the user types some text in the search bar the ListView gets updated and now if a particular checkbox associated with a specific row in the list is clicked it returns the wrong  item (different list item). I am not getting any idea why is this happening. My codes are as follows:

**FriendPicker Activity**(containing the list and the search bar :- relevant code of the OnCreate method):

```
            public class FriendPicker extends Activity 
            {
                EditText inputSearch;
                FriendListAdapter adapter;
                ArrayList<Friend> friends, searchResults;
                List<GraphUser> FriendList = null , selected = null;
                ListView listView;
                ImageView img = null;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
                {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friend_picker);

                    CliqueApplication application = (CliqueApplication) getApplication();
                    FriendList = application.getSelectedUsers();

                    friends = new ArrayList<Friend>();
                    selected = new ArrayList<GraphUser>();searchResults = new ArrayList<Friend>(friends);
                    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friendlist);
                    adapter = new FriendListAdapter(this,R.layout.friend, searchResults);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
                    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.done);

                    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
                        {
                            // When user changed the Text
                            //FriendPicker.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  
                             String searchString=inputSearch.getText().toString();
                               int textLength=searchString.length();

                                      //clear the initial data set
                               searchResults.clear();

                               for(int i=0;i<friends.size();i++)
                               {
                                  String playerName=friends.get(i).getName().toString();
                                  if(textLength<=playerName.length())
                                  {
                                  //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                                    if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0,textLength)))
                                    searchResults.add(friends.get(i));
                                  }
                               }
                               //adapter.setData(searchResults);
                               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                               //adapter.setData(friends);
                        }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) 
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
                {                        
                }
                });
            }
```

**FriendListAdapter.java**

```
             public class FriendListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend> 
    {
        ArrayList<Friend> data = null;
        Context context;
        public FriendListAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,ArrayList<Friend> items) 
        {
            super(context, resourceId, items);
            this.context = context;
            this.data = items;

        }
        private class ViewHolder 
        {
            ImageView Photo;
            TextView Name;
            CheckBox box;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            final Friend friend = getItem(position);
            //final Friend friend = (Friend)( parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.friend, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.Photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fphoto);
                holder.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fname);
                holder.box = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkbx);
                holder.box.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
                { 
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    { 
                     CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ; 
                     //Friend friend = (Friend) cb.getTag();
                     friend.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                     Log.i("Friend Adapter", friend.getName() + " checked is "+cb.isChecked());
                     //friend.setSelected(true);
                    } 
                   }); 
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } 
            else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            if (friend.getPhoto() != null) 
            {
                holder.Photo.setImageBitmap(friend.getPhoto());
            } 
            else 
            {
                holder.Photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.generic_profile_man);
            }
            holder.Name.setText(friend.getName());
            holder.box.setChecked(friend.isSelected());
            //holder.Name.setTag(friend);
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

I have one more doubt, when I am calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in onTextChanged method why the data in the FriendListAdapter is not showing the desired results on using getItem(position) in the getView() method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> checkbox associated with a specific row in the list is clicked it
>   returns the wrong item (different list item)

Because your are not getting correct friend object at `OnClickListener.onClick` method. `convertView` won't be inflated if it is not null so your `OnClickListener` instance. And you are going to use initial friend instance at that `OnClickListener` instance for your reused views.

To solve it:

1) At the end of getView method set current friend object as tag of your checkBox:

```
holder.box.setTag(friend);
return convertView;
```

2) You can do what you need with OnClickListener but I prefer using CheckBox's OnCheckedChangeListener:

```
holder.box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
       CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) buttonView ; 
       Friend friend = (Friend) cb.getTag();
       friend.setSelected(isChecked);
       Log.i("Friend Adapter", friend.getName() + " checked is "+isChecked);
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried the first method and its working correctly. But the second method is not working properly. Anyways thanks a lot for your answer :) My problem is fixed.

Comment: Actually 2 items are combined. They are not alternatives of each other. You had to use both.